# How to specify type of script

Tags: theming

I need to specify the type of script in my **theme.info**
I add the script in my **theme.info** like this `scripts[] = js/file.js`
In the head it look like this

`<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>`

but i need to change the type to

`type="application/ld+json"`

Can someone help me please

Comment: Khaled, Please give Correct Question Titles else you will get more down votes as people think this question is irrelevant to drupal.

Comment: ok thans, but it's my first question so i'm not familiar with this site

Comment: This link will guide you for adding questions on this forum. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

Drupal core adds the text/javascript as default type.

You may include the file using drupal_add_js

```
drupal_add_js('file.js', array('attributes' => array('id' => 'my-template', 'type' => 'application/ld+json')));
```

Comment: i should add this code in theme.php  ???

Comment: You may use drupal_add_js in your custom module file or if you want the js to be included for all pages declare it in the hook_init(). Check this link for more info: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7