# How can I change the 'type' of Drupal script tags from text/javascript to text/plain?

Tags: 7, javascript, cookies

I could use some assistance in figuring out a way to change script tags for a Drupal 7 site to be `"text/plain"`  instead of `"text/javascript"` And additional attribute(s).  I can tell already that script injection is something that is all over the board when it comes to implementation. Facebook 'pixel' for example is injecting script code outside of the `drupal_add_js` mechanism. And there are plenty of script tags added in templates (which are simple to change as necessary) but I would like to come up with a solution for the actual Drupal injected scripts, and nothing I’ve tried has worked yet.

### Reasoning

This change is required by the service provided via https://eucookie.eu/ for handling GDPR related functionality.  I technically only need to change scripts that are adding cookies.

### What I've tried without success

**Implementing hook_js_alter() in a module**

This provides access to some script information, but I don't see a way to change the script `type` attribute at all.  I can however add attributes, just not alter the `type` as necessary.

**Implementing phptemplate_preprocess_html_tag**

```
mytheme_preprocess_html_tag(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#tag'] == 'script') {
    $variables['element']['#attributes']['type'] = 'text/plain';
    $variables['element']['#attributes']['data-cookie-if'] = 'analytical';
  }
}
```

The additional attribute of `data-cookie-if` IS being added as expected.  But the type is not being changed, in fact, there is no type at all in the resulting markup.

### Additional complications

Script Aggregation if enabled will add another twist, and I'm fairly certain I will need to disable this, but still wanted to mention in case there is a preferred workaround.

Comment: Did you try this? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173415/how-to-specify-type-of-script/173425

Comment: Thanks beau.  This is helpful info to know.  I wasn't able to solve my issue with this since I was trying to manipulate contributed modules scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I solved, mostly by implementing the `theme_process_html_tag` method in the template.  Note the **PROCESS** not **PRE**process.

In my case, the theme was extending the 'zen' theme, which was actually removing all 'type' attributes from scripts in the header (I don't know exactly why).  But I was able to overwrite this behavior in the theme hook mentioned above.